# Using a list of characters in a function?

Tags: r

I am using a function where Timepoints need to be defined as
`Timepoints = c(x,y,z)`

Now i have a chr list

```
List 

  $ chr: "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
```

with the timepoints i need to use, already seperated by commas.
I want to use this list in the function and lose the quotation marks, so the function can read my timepoints as

`Timepoints= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`

I tried using noquote(List), but this is not accepted.

Am is missing something ? printing the list with `noquote()` results in the desired line of characters `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

Comment: The purported duplicate is close but is not exactly the same as this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Base R - scan** Assuming that you have a list containing a single character string  as shown in `L` below use `scan` as shown.

```
L <- list("1,2,3,4,5,6")
scan(text = L[[1]], sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

**2) gsubfn::strapply**  Another possibility is to use strapply to match each string of digits, convert them to numeric and return it as a vector. (We assume that the numbers have no signs or decimal points but that could readily be added if needed.)

```
library(gsubfn)

strapply(L[[1]], "\\d+", as.numeric, simplify = unlist)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

### Added

In a comment the poster indicated an interest in having a list of character strings as input.  The output was not specified but if we assume we want a list of numeric vectors then

```
L2 <- list(A = "1,2,3,4,5,6", B = "1,2")

Scan <- function(x) scan(text = x, sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)
lapply(L2, Scan)
## $A
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
## 
## $B
## [1] 1 2

library(gsubfn)
strapply(L2, "\\d", as.numeric)
## $A
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
##
## $B
## [1] 1 2
```

Comment: works fine with the case i mentioned, but doesn't work when I use text such as a list of $ " 'A' , 'B' , 'C' " , but @RuiBarradas option using strsplit works with both !

Comment: If that is required it should be covered in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `strsplit`.

```
as.integer(unlist(strsplit(L[[1]], ",")))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```